# Proper way to Implement a Birthday Class in Object Oriented Python

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following class

```
class Dob:
    def __init__(self):
        self.welcome_text = ""
    
    #Computes DOB
    def calc_dob(self):
        pass

    #Get User Input
    def get_input(self, msg):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.welcome_text)
        total_days = self.calc_dob()
        return str(total_days)
```

And calls it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Dob())
```

Initially I thought this is OK but importing it into PyCharm IDE, it shows warning that methods *calc_dob* and *get_input* could be static.

Following the IDE's suggestion, it moves the methods outside of the class.

All that is left is the *__repr__* method .That makes me think something is wrong with the Class above.

Is the code OK, and I should just rather mark the methods with *@staticmethod* annotation? or my idea isn't Object Oriented and how can I make it Object Oriented.

Any help will be appreciated please.

**EDIT:**
I remove the codes (*implementation for the methods*) for simplicity in posting here. The reasons for the warning are that I am not using instances of the Class. What I'm asking is if this is a proper Implementation

Comment: I think PyCharm told that `calc_dob` and `get_input` need to be static. since there are no code inside those methods. Maybe it would work well once those methods are implemented

Comment: @tvgriek's comments are good here.  A "birthday" object should hold a date.  It shouldn't be printing a welcome message.   It shouldn't be asking for input.  The I/O is the responsibility of the caller.  You don't know whether this object will always be used with a console or not.

Comment: Thanks alot @TimRoberts. I think I'm getting this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a DoB object should have one job: hold the date of birth. Question is if this even needed. We have date objects for this already. Calculations on DoB would rather live in a DOBHelper object or function. The reason pycharm moves the methods is because you are not using any class variables in them.